# SQL SERVER select substring

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a table like this...

```
+------------+----------+
|    NPA     |   nama   |
+------------+----------+
| 0101010003 | adi      |
| 0101020004 | adu      |
| 0101030005 | ade      |
| 0102010006 | abi      |
| 0103010007 | 25910015 |
+------------+----------+
```

I have variable like this : `$npa1 = 01`, `$npa2 = 02`, `$npa3 = 03`

How to make SQL server 2014 query to get npa with first character `010101xxxx` and `010102xxxx` and `010103xxxx`
How can make it in SQL server 2014 and PHP?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where left(npa, 6) in ('0101' + $npa1, '0101' + $npa2, '0101' + $npa3);
```

That said, you should be using parameters to pass values into the query, rather than munging strings.